# Header with menu disappearing in responsive mood in wordpress Node theme

Tags: css, wordpress

I am using Node child theme for my site. The header and menu works fine in the desktop mode but when it is shrinked to responsive mood the heading with menu disappeares. I have tried allmost all the options but none is working. I couldn't find any documentation of the theme and any specific solution on the net. My site url is-
http://onlineinternetquest.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add This code in your mobile media query

```
header.edgtf-mobile-header {
    display: block !important;
}
header.edgtf-mobile-header .edgtf-mobile-header-inner {
    height: auto;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I needed to change a bit but it was useful

Answer (score 1):

You have `media-query` in your css that says under `1024px`  `display: none;` to head.

See screen shot from F12:

[image]

> **So remove this `media-query`:**

```
media only screen and (max-width: 1024px)
.edgtf-page-header, .edgtf-top-bar {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: tell me for more help

Comment: Thanks. That I have also noticed. But can you please specify which file? I couldn't find the file.

Comment: happy to help:) by the way to finf the file use Ctrl+Shift+F and put the text you want to find(like `edgtf-page-header`)